# Breadcrumb navigation with Permissions

Tags: angular, angular7-router

I wrote the code for breadcrumb and its working fine but facing an issue with permissions.
Example: One module name: `TestModulewhich` is lazy-loaded, and there are many components i.e. `TestComponent1, TestComponent2,...` etc.
Breadcrumb will be like Test Module/Test Component 1 if I click on `TestCOmponent1` and similarly for `TestComponent2`.
If I click on Test module in breadcrumb it should redirect to Test Component 1 which is working fine but if I don't have the permission for Test Component 1 then it throwing 403 forbidden.
I need it should redirect to TestComponent 2 if I don't have permission for Test Component 1.

I tried multiple solutions but none of them working.
breadcrumb code :

```
 // Private Helper method to calculate breadcrumb
    private getBreadcrumbs(route: ActivatedRoute, url: string = '', breadcrumbs: Breadcrumb[] = []): Breadcrumb[] {

        const pageTitle = 'pageTitle';

        while (route) {
            // checking router outlet is primary or not
            if (route.outlet !== PRIMARY_OUTLET) {
                return breadcrumbs;
            }
            if (!!(route.snapshot.data.hasOwnProperty(pageTitle))) {
                if (!breadcrumbs.find(item => item.label === route.snapshot.data[pageTitle])) {
                    //If no url is avalailable we are on the root url
                    const routeURL: string = route.snapshot.url.map(segment => segment.path).join('/');
                    if (routeURL !== '' && !!(route.snapshot.data[pageTitle])) {
                        //In the routeURL the complete path is not available,
                        //so we rebuild it each time
                        url += `/${routeURL}`;
                        breadcrumbs.push({
                            label: route.snapshot.data[pageTitle],
                            url: url,
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            route = route.firstChild;
        }
        return breadcrumbs;
    }
```

breadcrumb template:

```
<div aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li *ngFor="let breadcrumb of breadcrumbs; let last = last" aria-current="page" class="breadcrumb-item active">
            <a *ngIf="!last" [routerLink]="breadcrumb.url" class="breadcrumb-text">{{ breadcrumb.label }}</a>
            <span *ngIf="last" class="breadcrumb-text">{{ breadcrumb.label }}</span>
        </li>
        <li *ngIf="breadCrumbsAdditionalText" class="breadcrumb-item active">
            <span class="breadcrumb-text">{{breadCrumbsAdditionalText}}</span>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

and the routing where I am using this :

```
    const route = [{ path: '', redirectTo:'testmodule/testcomponent1', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'testmodule',component: ContentWrapper,data: {pageTitle: 'test Module'},children = [{path: 'testcomponent1',component: TestComponent1,data:{pageTitle: 'Test Component 1'},
},{path: 'testcomponent2',component: TestComponent2,data:{pageTitle: 'Test Component 2'}}]
```